# How to integrate PayTm gateway with nodeJS or with Reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paytm

I am integrating Paytm payment gateway in my web app. I am using React for front end and nodeJs for back end.

I've made paytm post request successfully and everything is working fine but my callback url is making problems. I am getting data successfully I can see it in my network tab but when I am console logging `req.body` it is showing an empty object.

This is response I am getting from paytm

[image: This is response I am getting from paytm]

This where I am posting up the data

```
app.get('/user/recharge/mywallet' , (req, res) => {

    /* initialize an object with request parameters */
    var paytmParams = {
        "MID" : "my merchant id",
        "WEBSITE" : "WEBSTAGING",
        "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" : "Retail",

        /* WEB for website and WAP for Mobile-websites or App */
        "CHANNEL_ID" : "WEB",

        /* Enter your unique order id */
        "ORDER_ID" : "2213211",

        /* unique id that belongs to your customer */
        "CUST_ID" : "3221211",
        /**
        * Amount in INR that is payble by customer
        * this should be numeric with optionally having two decimal points
        */
        "TXN_AMOUNT" : "200",

        /* on completion of transaction, we will send you the response on this URL */
        "CALLBACK_URL" : "http://localhost:3001/true/paytmresp",
    };

    checksum.genchecksum(paytmParams, "My Merchant Key", function(err, checksum){
        /* for Staging */
        let url = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process";
        /* Prepare HTML Form and Submit to Paytm */
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<head>');
        res.write('<title>Merchant Checkout Page</title>');
        res.write('</head>');
        res.write('<body>');
        res.write('<center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>');
        res.write('<form method="post" action="' + url + '" name="paytm_form">');
        for(let x in paytmParams){
            res.write('<input type="hidden" name="' + x + '" value="' + paytmParams[x] + '">');
        }
        res.write('<input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="' + checksum + '">');
        res.write('</form>');
        res.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
        res.write('document.paytm_form.submit();');
        res.write('</script>');
        res.write('</body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        res.end();
        if(err) {
            console.log("err: ", err);
        }
        console.log('checksum: ', checksum);
    })
})

    app.post('/true/paytmresp', (req, res) => {
        console.log("body: ", req.body);
    })
```

I want to put my paytm response into variables so I can verify and add that to db

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this? I am facing similar problem as well.

Comment: You have missed adding body-parser in app.js

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json())

Comment: I have already answered this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281162/how-to-add-paytm-gateway-integration-in-react-js-web-application/68103299#68103299

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding body-parser in app.js

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json())