# How do i make payment paytm using react js i have already build api in spring boot

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to integrate paytm payment in my web app. i am following [Paytm payment gateway](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/payment-gateway/)

Till step two it's working fine. but at step three i am not able to post request with paytm URL by using react js --"Customer fills payment details and completes the payment authentication. Once the payment is complete, response is posted as HTML form POST on your app/website's callback URL"

How do i do this in react js only.

Comment: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/?utm_source=Business_Website

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281162/how-to-add-paytm-gateway-integration-in-react-js-web-application/68103299#68103299) check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281162/how-to-add-paytm-gateway-integration-in-react-js-web-application/68103299#68103299

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the call back response through backend as checksum need to verify. Also do the status query from backend before showing the success response to user